# Ruby 2.1.0 valid? not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.1.0. I am wondering is there a bug in the ***valid?*** method? I got the following output in my rails console which is in test mode:

```
2.1.0 :018 > e1
 => #<Employer id: 3, first_name: "Test 2", last_name: "Case", email: "abc@d.sun", created_at: "2014-02-13 11:53:35", updated_at: "2014-02-13 11:53:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$JfCeRCMUESYgDGoBerqaZ.jEuEnyWPqrZ4K6L/sSOzsD..."> 
2.1.0 :019 > e1.valid?
  Employer Exists (2.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "employers" WHERE (LOWER("employers"."email") = LOWER('abc@d.sun') AND "employers"."id" != 3) LIMIT 1
=> false
```

In the SQL it says:

```
"employers"."id" != 3
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
"employers"."id" = 3
```

considering that the id for the employer is 3.

However, I am able to authenticate the same employer. So is there a problem with my controller or model instead? Well, I'm confused.

```
2.1.0 :020 > e1.authenticate( "foobar" )
 => #<Employer id: 3, first_name: "Test 2", last_name: "Case", email: "abc@d.sun", created_at: "2014-02-13 11:53:35", updated_at: "2014-02-13 11:53:35", password_digest: "$2a$04$JfCeRCMUESYgDGoBerqaZ.jEuEnyWPqrZ4K6L/sSOzsD...">
```

Controller

```
class EmployersController < ApplicationController
  def new

    @employer = Employer.new(employer_params)
    if @employer.save

      redirect_to @employer
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @employer.update_attributes(employer_params)
      redirect_to @employer
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  private
    def employer_params
      params.require(:employer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
    end
end
```

Model

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_secure_password

    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase! }


    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope, it is looking for other records with the same email, since you want it to be unique.

Comment: Which can be a confusing place, especially when you start to look a bit behind the scenes like in this case.

Answer (score 2):

That's a uniqueness validation querying the database for other records with the same email.